# jsf button deletes a variable?

Tags: spring, user-interface, jsf, button, xhtml

I want to show the participants of an event, the event is saved in `allEventsView.selectedEvent`.

Until this moment `allEventsView.selectedEvent` is not `null`. This button opens a dialog:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-comment" title="Teilnehmer" oncomplete="PF('participationDialog').show()" rendered="#{not empty allEventsView.selectedEvent.participants}"></p:commandButton>
```

Here is the dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="Teilnehmer" widgetVar="participationDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="participationDetail" style="text-align:center;">
        <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{allEventsView.selectedEvent.participants}">
            <p:column headerText="User:">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

But the dataTable is empty (no records found). And yes: `allEventsView.selectedEvent` is null, not `allEventsView.selectedEvent.participants`.

Note: the button is also part of a dialog. So, one dialog opens an other dialog.

Comment: if it helps: the button is also part of a dialog. So: one dialog opens an other dialog

Comment: Is selectedEvent already set on initial page load or is it set on user action (maybe by clicking a button or something like this)? If it's set on user action, please show the part where it is set. Maybe you didn't update the dialog in this part.

Comment: [mcve] please...